# Delete all rows in database using struts and torque

Tags: java, struts, apache-torque

I need to delete a more than one row in database.

The data is in `Tariff` table which include another table's (`vehicle`) primary key.

Suppose if I delete a `vehicle` table data, the data which one is related to that particular id in `tariff` table also is deleted.

I tried, if the `tariff` contains more than two rows related to `vehicle` that I need to delete, and delete the first one in `tariff` table others are not deleted.

**Here is a code:**

```
Vehicle vehicle = VehiclePeer.doSelectFirst(c);
if (vehicleName != null && !vehicleName.equals(""))
{                   
  c.clear();
  c.add(TariffPeer.VEHICLE_ID, vehicle.getId());
  Tariff tariff = (Tariff) TariffPeer.doSelectAll();
  if (tariff != null && !tariff.equals(""))
  {
    TariffParamsPeer.doDelete(c.add(TariffParamsPeer.TARIFF_ID, tariff.getId()));
    TariffPeer.doDelete(tariff);
  }
}
```

Please, help me to sort out this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a method that retun a set of `Tariff` for the given vheicleId. And rewrite the code as follows

```
Vehicle vehicle = VehiclePeer.doSelectFirst(c);
if (vehicleName != null && !vehicleName.equals("")) {                    
  c.clear();
  c.add(TariffPeer.VEHICLE_ID,vehicle.getId());
  Set<Tariff> tarrifSet = TariffPeer.doSelectAll(vehicle.getId());
  for (Tariff tariff: tarrifSet) { 
    if (tariff !=null && !tariff.equals("")) {       
      c.add(TariffParamsPeer.TARIFF_ID, tariff.getId());
      TariffPeer.doDelete(tariff);
    }
  }
}
```